# How to connect two directives to the same function in Angular?

Tags: angular, mouseevent

I have a pooper that displays a DIV when the rat enters and hides the DIV when the rat exits. Since I'm using `classList.toggle("hidden")`, I realize that I can call the same method from both events like this (it works just dandy).

```ts
<td (mouseenter)="pooper($event,row)" 
    (mouseleave)="pooper($event,row)">
    {{row.info}}
    <div class="pooper hidden">PoopUp</div>
</td>
```

However, I want to recall that there's a way to register for both in one take. I thought I could do the following but it seems that nothing gets listened to (likely due to a syntax error). There are no errors reported and googling for the syntax or any example gave me nothing (possibly due to poor keyword choice on my behalf).

```ts
<td (mouseenter,mouseleave)="pooper($event,row)">
    {{row.info}}
    <div class="pooper hidden">PoopUp</div>
</td>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This thread is [under discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348225/is-this-question-not-related-to-angular). I'm locking the post until the discussion gets cleared up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported and doesn't seem to be planned for the near future https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6675#issuecomment-251009636

Comment: It definitely **should be** supported. Do you have any thoughts on the rationale regarding the reason behind that not being warmly appreciated? Seems to be that it'd be just syntactic sugar for the multi-directive version and make the code smoother.

Comment: There are several extensions to the syntax considered (related to observables and newer browser developments). I guess they first want to be sure everything is considered before actually making changes. This syntax can't be changed easily later in case they figure out they should have done something similar.